# If condition question

Tags: grammar

If he hadn't had the news , what would he ( has - have ) done ?

Well, I doubt it's ( have ) but not sure. And I can't find keywords to search for in either google or stackexchange.

Comment: Allow me to introduce you to the magic of [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=would+he+has+done%2C+would+he+have+done&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwould%20he%20have%20done%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: ngrams are only good for written English, and only some of it at that. A very small subset of English, and very hard to search for actual phenomena instead of just strings of words.

Comment: @JohnLawler: All valid points, but if said string is 'not found' at all, as in this case, it's pretty safe to assume that the string is not grammatical/idiomatic. Since the OP had trouble researching, I just thought I'd point him to a new tool.

Comment: Do raw Google searches on "what would he has done" and "what would he have done".

Comment: The problem is that strings can't be ungrammatical. Grammaticality is a property of constituents, not of their bits and pieces. Random strings of amino acids are not genes.

Comment: @TusharRaj , Does ngrams check if this word was used in literature ? Nice tool indeed.

Comment: This is not about any conditional, but about conjugation verbs. Leave the first part out and even forget the question. That leaves us with the statement: "He would has/have done something". _Would_ is the conjugated verb here, meaning that the others should be infinitives or participles: he would _have_ done something.

Answer (score 2):

> If he hadn't had the news, what would he **have** done?

The non-interrogative form is "he would have done". The word "have" is actually infinitive here and not indicative, because of the "would" before it - this is why it's "have" and not "has". It's *he **has** done* but *he would **have** done*.